# C for loop, testing array elements gives weird result

Tags: c, for-loop

I can't figure out what I did wrong. I want to print non-zero elements and the below code prints none.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int arr[4] = { 0, 3, 0, 7 };
    // print non zero elements
    for (int i = 0; i != 4 && arr[i] != 0; ++i)
        printf("%d\t%d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

But if I move the array test like the below, it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int arr[4] = { 0, 3, 0, 7 };
    // print non zero elements
    for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] != 0)
           printf("%d\t%d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I think you got it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the first loop is different from the second loop is that the first loop quits as soon as `i` reaches the position of the first zero in the array, while the second loop always goes all the way up to the forth element.

Your first loop is equivalent to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] != 0)
       printf("%d\t%d\n", i, arr[i]);
    else
        break;
}
```

Breaking on seeing zero is what makes the first loop to terminate early.

Comment: why would it quit for the first zero in the array? this is not a while loop.

Comment: @BestCoderEver The form of the loop doesn't matter: `for` loop is just like a `while` loop, but it has two more "compartments" in the loop header - for initialization, and for advancing loop variable. The loop condition in a `for` loop is the same as the "continuation condition" of a `while` loop. In your case, that's `i != 4 && arr[i] != 0`, so your loop would stop at the first zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i != 4 && arr[i] != 0; ++i)
```

The loop instantly terminates if `arr[i] == 0`. Ans as the first element already **is** `0`, it is not even run once.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is your first for loop is equivalent to this:

```
int i=0;
while(i!=4&&arr[i]!=0)
{
  printf("%d\t%d\n", i, arr[i]);
  ++i;
}
```

**That is the condition is being checked in the beginning and therefore your loop terminates before it can begin its first iteration.**